Menu links in UI bootstrap theme breaking menu in Blazor Web App?
So I have a Bootstrap theme thai I want to use with my Blazor Web App. Problem is, that the menu items are causing a route navigation instead of dropping down menu drop downs? How can I fix this?
  <li class="pc-item pc-hasmenu">
          <a href="#!" class="pc-link"><span class="pc-micon"> <i class="ph-duotone ph-layout"></i></span><span class="pc-mtext">Layouts</span><span class="pc-arrow"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-chevron-right"><polyline points="9 18 15 12 9 6"></polyline></svg></span></a>
          <ul class="pc-submenu" style="display: none;">
            <li class="pc-item"><a class="pc-link" href="/">Horizontal</a></li>
            <li class="pc-item"><a class="pc-link" href="/">Vertical</a></li>
            <li class="pc-item"><a class="pc-link" href="/">Vertical + Tab</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

Hope someone can help out.

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

Found the answer, you must add @onclick:preventDefault and it ignores the routing:
 <a href="!#" class="pc-link" @onclick:preventDefault>
            <span class="pc-micon">
              <i class="ph-duotone ph-gauge"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="pc-mtext">Dashboard</span>
            <span class="pc-arrow"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-chevron-right"><polyline points="9 18 15 12 9 6"></polyline></svg></span>
            <span class="pc-badge">2</span>
          </a>

